# Background image is not getting printed

Tags: html, css

I have  used a container in my HTML page, where i used a background image. 
I want to put some text on top of my background image, and print it.
But When I use :

```
<A HREF="javascript:window.print()">Print</A>
```

I dont get my background image at all.
this is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
</head>
<body >
<div id="headerbg">
<h1><p>DATA</h1>
</div> 
<div id="container">
    <p id="address">
    adress is XYZ
    </p>
    <p id="ward">
    Ward is 7
    </p>
</div>
<A HREF="javascript:window.print()">Print</A>
 <div id="footer">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The css I used is:

```
#headerbg {
    background:#E8E8E8;
    text-align:center;
     height: 80px;
    }

#headerbg p{
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 40%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    }
#container
{   background-image: url("notice.jpg");
    height:680px;
    width:1000px;
     background-repeat: no-repeat; 
     margin-top:10px;
     margin-left:390px;
    position:relative;
}

#address
{
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;    
    color:black;
    font-size:19px;
    left:10px;
    top:225px;
}
```

How can I make my background image printable? please help me!

Comment: try with inline style for #container ? without using style class ?

Comment: If you are using Windows 7, when the print dialog appears, there is an option called `More Settings` below the option `Color`. Click on that and you will see a `checkbox` called `Background Graphics`. Tick that and you will see the background image.

Comment: Simply awsome !! Thank u so much :)))) @PrerakSola

Comment: You are welcome. For a partial solution using `css`, see the answer I have posted. And if it helps, do mark it as the correct one... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Windows 7, when the print dialog appears, there is an option called `More Settings` below the option `Color`. Click on that and you will see a `check box` called `Background Graphics`. Tick that and you will see the background image.

Also, for Chrome and Safari you can add the following in your CSS:

```
@media print
{
    * {-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;}
}
```

This will print the `background image` even if the option is not selected in the print dialog. For other web browsers unfortunately it's up to the user to manually select the option to print background images (e.g. for users with IE 9, 10 and 11 they have to click on the cog icon -> Print -> Page Setup, and activate the option)

Answer (score 1):

Add media print:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="" media="print"/>
```

or, you can set in css, as in:

```
@media print {
body {
   content:'url(../imagez.png)';
  }
}
```

note: some IE not work by using that, you can use:

```
@import 'style.css' print;
```

Comment: Background image is still not coming in the print preview :(