# CSS alignment on different browsers

Tags: css

Don't use CSS very much so this might be a simple solution. I'm trying to align a dynamic date value on a jpg certificate in the lower righthand corner. its aligned on a fixed image line. Alignment looks great in safari browser, but shifts to the right on Chrome and Firefox and shifts far to the left in Internet Explorer. example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffbarclay/evu1y9ao/

```
.certDate {
font-size:14pt;
font-family:Trebuchet MS;
font-weight:normal; 
position: absolute;  
top: 480px; 
left: 780px;   
}
```

Comment: Give html please. Better yet set up a jsfiddle example.

Comment: Have you tried to position top and left with `%` ?

Comment: im not sure how jsfiddle would show the different browser results, I'll try % and see Thanks

Comment: ok, % does the same thing... is the same results on firefox and Chrome but shifts in safari?

Comment: can you post your full code for better understanding? @BarclayVision

Comment: here is a http://jsfiddle.net/jeffbarclay/evu1y9ao/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use right and bottom instead of left and top.

```
.certDate {
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-family: Trebuchet MS;
    font-weight: normal; 
    position: absolute;  
    bottom: 0; 
    right: 0;   
}
```

Make sure the container has proper height and width and position is relative.

Comment: i'm not sure how to set container? here is http://jsfiddle.net/jeffbarclay/evu1y9ao/

Comment: Something like like: http://jsfiddle.net/evu1y9ao/1/.  Instead of an <img>, I used a <div> with a background of your image to act as the container of the other elements.  Then you can position the inner elements relative to that.

Comment: brilliant, thanks so much, thats what I was looking for.

Comment: one last question - not sure if the div vs img is causing this but when I print, the certificate.jpg is no longer printed? `<center> <input type=button onClick="window.print()" value="Print This Page"/> </center>` see: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffbarclay/evu1y9ao/2/

Comment: I see this can be turned on in printer setting, but can it be done via javascript? background graphics: on, headers and footers: off

Comment: found solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473239/background-image-is-not-getting-printed/28473843#28473843

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers have different default-css rules. To factor all of that out, it is often best practice to download a normalize.css file and attach it to your projects. It adjusts things like the default body margins and padding so that everything is consistent. You can download it from here:

[Normalise.css git](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

resolved by adding `<div class='certificate;>` in place of `img` Thanks @Adam Milecki

```
.certificate {
background-image: url(http://www.mcfrsit.com/TestCert/quizimages/cert.png);
background-size: 100% 100%;
height: 300px;
width: 800px;
padding: 50px;
position: relative;
}

.certDate {
font-size: 14pt;
font-family: Trebuchet MS;
font-weight:normal;
position: absolute;
bottom: 50px;
right: 100px; 
}

.certHead {
font-size:40pt;
font-family:Trebuchet MS; 
position: absolute; 
top: 130px; 
left: 0; 
width: 100%;  
}

.certBody {
font-size:28pt;
font-family:Trebuchet MS;
font-weight:normal;
width: 100%;  
}
```